# Bitnami - /opt/bitnami/python/bin/.python2.7.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.5

Tags: python, django, centos, bitnami

I getting the below issue when firing up django or ipython notebook

**/opt/bitnami/python/bin/.python2.7.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.5**

However libreadline.so.5 exists in my system after locating it as shown below

**root@linux:/opt/bitnami/scripts# locate libreadline.so.5
/opt/bitnami/common/lib/libreadline.so.5
/opt/bitnami/common/lib/libreadline.so.5.2**

I have also exported the path in the environment variable (where the libreadlive.so.5 is located) but still does'nt seems to be resolving my issue (see below)

**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$HOME/opt/bitnami/common/lib**

Also there is a script which is being provided by bitnami which is located in /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh. But even after executing it still i am stuck.

Anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 7):

Can you execute the following and see if it solves your issue?

. /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh

(notice the space between the dot and the path to the script)

Also what are you executing that gives you that error?

Comment: I had a similar message while installing Scrapy on djangostack-1.4.5-0. Running '. /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh' solved it. Sorry I can't vote your answer up - I'm only new here

Comment: is solves but it is required everytime we do something, why is this required, what is this?